# Spark collect_set from a column using window function approach

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a sample dataset with salaries. I want to distribute that salary into 3 buckets and then find the lower of the salary in each bucket and then convert that into an array and attach it to the original set. I am trying to use window function to do that. And it seems to do it in a progressive fashion.

Here is the code that I have written

```scala
val spark = sparkSession
import spark.implicits._
    
val simpleData = Seq(("James", "Sales", 3000),
  ("Michael", "Sales", 3100),
  ("Robert", "Sales", 3200),
  ("Maria", "Finance", 3300),
  ("James", "Sales", 3400),
  ("Scott", "Finance", 3500),
  ("Jen", "Finance", 3600),
  ("Jeff", "Marketing", 3700),
  ("Kumar", "Marketing", 3800),
  ("Saif", "Sales", 3900)
)
val df = simpleData.toDF("employee_name", "department", "salary")
val windowSpec = Window.orderBy("salary")
val ntileFrame = df.withColumn("ntile", ntile(3).over(windowSpec))
val lowWindowSpec = Window.partitionBy("ntile")
val ntileMinDf = ntileFrame.withColumn("lower_bound", min("salary").over(lowWindowSpec))
var rangeDf = ntileMinDf.withColumn("range", collect_set("lower_bound").over(windowSpec))
rangeDf.show()
```

I am getting the dataset like this

```
+-------------+----------+------+-----+-----------+------------------+
|employee_name|department|salary|ntile|lower_bound|             range|
+-------------+----------+------+-----+-----------+------------------+
|        James|     Sales|  3000|    1|       3000|            [3000]|
|      Michael|     Sales|  3100|    1|       3000|            [3000]|
|       Robert|     Sales|  3200|    1|       3000|            [3000]|
|        Maria|   Finance|  3300|    1|       3000|            [3000]|
|        James|     Sales|  3400|    2|       3400|      [3000, 3400]|
|        Scott|   Finance|  3500|    2|       3400|      [3000, 3400]|
|          Jen|   Finance|  3600|    2|       3400|      [3000, 3400]|
|         Jeff| Marketing|  3700|    3|       3700|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|        Kumar| Marketing|  3800|    3|       3700|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|         Saif|     Sales|  3900|    3|       3700|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
+-------------+----------+------+-----+-----------+------------------+
```

I am expecting the dataset to look like this

```
+-------------+----------+------+-----+-----------+------------------+
|employee_name|department|salary|ntile|lower_bound|             range|
+-------------+----------+------+-----+-----------+------------------+
|        James|     Sales|  3000|    1|       3000|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|      Michael|     Sales|  3100|    1|       3000|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|       Robert|     Sales|  3200|    1|       3000|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|        Maria|   Finance|  3300|    1|       3000|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|        James|     Sales|  3400|    2|       3400|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|        Scott|   Finance|  3500|    2|       3400|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|          Jen|   Finance|  3600|    2|       3400|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|         Jeff| Marketing|  3700|    3|       3700|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|        Kumar| Marketing|  3800|    3|       3700|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|         Saif|     Sales|  3900|    3|       3700|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
+-------------+----------+------+-----+-----------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure that your windows take into account all rows and not only rows before current row, you can use `rowsBetween` method with `Window.unboundedPreceding` and `Window.unboundedFollowing` as argument. Your last line thus become:

```scala
var rangeDf = ntileMinDf.withColumn(
  "range",
  collect_set("lower_bound")
     .over(Window.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing))
)
```

and you get the following `rangeDf` dataframe:

```
+-------------+----------+------+-----+-----------+------------------+
|employee_name|department|salary|ntile|lower_bound|             range|
+-------------+----------+------+-----+-----------+------------------+
|        James|     Sales|  3000|    1|       3000|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|      Michael|     Sales|  3100|    1|       3000|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|       Robert|     Sales|  3200|    1|       3000|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|        Maria|   Finance|  3300|    1|       3000|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|        James|     Sales|  3400|    2|       3400|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|        Scott|   Finance|  3500|    2|       3400|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|          Jen|   Finance|  3600|    2|       3400|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|         Jeff| Marketing|  3700|    3|       3700|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|        Kumar| Marketing|  3800|    3|       3700|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
|         Saif|     Sales|  3900|    3|       3700|[3000, 3700, 3400]|
+-------------+----------+------+-----+-----------+------------------+
```

Comment: you can also write the code like this. 
`var rangeDf = ntileMinDf.withColumn("range", collect_set("lower_bound").over())`